# When should we use transclude in angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular js, recently I read about scopes and transclude in custom directives. I am looking for some use cases where transclude is used in angular directive.

There might be multiple scenarios, where different combinations of scope(true, false, {}) and transclude(true, false, element) is used.

It's a bit confusing to me, when to use what.

Answer (score 1):

[Angular documentation for directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is your friend

"What does this transclude option do, exactly? transclude makes the contents of a directive with this option have access to the scope outside of the directive rather than inside."

Go through examples there and it might be useful for  you to get insight into this.

Comment: I already went through the angular's developer guide, and I am able to understand what it is, but my doubt was, when to use it. Actually, to be precise, I wanted a use case.